# Should I raise INotifyPropertyChanged events if I don't have a corresponding property with that name on my class?

Tags: c#, events, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class that implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and *also* has its own concept of properties, a little bit like this:

```
class sealed MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> _properties;

    public object GetProperty(string name)
    {
        return _properties[name];
    }

    public object SomeProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return GetProperty("SomeProperty");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that some common properties also have C# accessors.

I want to raise an event to notify others that a property (whose value is accessed through the GetProperty method) has changed even if this property does not have a corresponding C# accessor.

Assuming that there is no risk of a clash (i.e. inadvertantly raising a property changed event for a C# property whose value has not changed - note that this class is sealed), is there any reason why I can't just use the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event  to notify others, or should I add my own event for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you add your own.  Although there's no specific reason that the code would break, `INotifyPropertyChanged` has a specific intended usage, and one that is understood by a lot of potential consumers.  I'd not personally write code that contradicts that, just in case.

Comment: I was going to suggest the opposite, but having had a think about it I think I agree with Dan. If you class implements both normal properties and dynamic properties, I think at the very least a separate event will signal to the consumer where to find that property.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no harm in raising `PropertyChanged` for a property that isn't there, but I don't think it's very useful either. `INotifyPropertyChanged` is mostly used by data binding systems (in WinForms, WPF, Silverlight...), and these system don't know how to access your custom "properties".

Now, what you could do is implement `ICustomTypeDescriptor` to provide access to your custom properties in a standard way. This works with Windows Forms and WPF, I'm not sure about other frameworks.

Of course, if your intention is not to use this for data binding, you can still use this event to notify consumers of your class that values have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it depends on who has subscribed to `PropertyChanged` and *what* they do in response to the `PropertyChanged` event.  If they don't try to read a .NET "property", you're fine.

But, that really introduces a coupling and the use of INPC is trying to decouple.  INPC at the general case assumes `PropertyChanged` means a .NET property (of a given name) has changed and is expected to be the case for all places that use INPC.  i.e. you implement INPC because you want to use your object in *any* place that accepts INPC.  If your object can't do that, then it violates the implied contract of INPC.  If you have a `PropertyChanged` handler that does something different than read a property and you're re-using INPC just because it's there then maybe writing you own interface is a good idea.